# Table cells don't match with table headings in Angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on a project which requires me to make table using *ngFor directive of Angular. But after several failed attempts I couldn't get the table layout properly . The table cells don't match up with headings and the width of table rows is also not consistent as you can see in the [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjukU.jpg) . I'm new to Angular and also don't have much experience in debugging css. I think the problem is due to *ngFor directive. Here is the HTML and CSS code snippet. There is *ngIf condition on each td as the table should show the data in a row only when the user clicks it. I'll be very thankful for any help or guidance given.

```css
* {
  color: hsla(210, 100%, 100%, 0.9) !important;
  background: hsla(210, 100%, 50%, 0.5) !important;
  outline: solid 0.25rem hsla(210, 100%, 100%, 0.5) !important;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
}

.heading {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 98.7%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

  <thead class="thead-dark">

    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">registrationNo</th>

      <!--adding heading to criterias using *ngFor -->
      <div formArrayName="participants" *ngFor="let candidate of myForm.controls.participants['controls'];let i  = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <div formArrayName="criteriaArray" class="d-inline-block" *ngFor="let criteria of candidate.get('criteriaArray').controls;let j  = index;">

            <div [formGroupName]="j">
              <th *ngIf="(i === 0) && (EditRowId2 !== criteria.get('id').value)" class="text-center" style="width: 100%" (click)="Edit2(criteria.get('id').value)">{{criteria.get('criteriaName').value}}</th>
              <th *ngIf="(i === 0) && (EditRowId2 === criteria.get('id').value)" class="text-center" style="width: 100%"><input type="text" formControlName="criteriaName"></th>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Maximum Marks</td>
      <!--adding maximum marks row to the table using *ngFor -->
      <div (click)="Edit(0)" formArrayName="participants" *ngFor="let candidate of myForm.controls.participants['controls'];let i  = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <div formArrayName="criteriaArray" class="d-inline-block" *ngFor="let criteria of candidate.get('criteriaArray').controls;let j  = index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="j">
              <td *ngIf="(i === 0) && (EditRowId2 !== criteria.get('id').value)" (click)="Edit2(criteria.get('id').value)">{{criteria.get('max_marks').value}}</td>
              <td *ngIf="(EditRowId2 === criteria.get('id').value) && (i===0)"> <input type="number" formControlName="max_marks"> </td>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </tr>

    <div formArrayName="participants" *ngFor="let candidate of myForm.controls.participants['controls'];let i  = index;" (click)=Edit2(0)>
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <tr>
          <td> {{candidate.get('registrationNo').value}} </td>


          <div formArrayName="criteriaArray" class="d-inline-block" *ngFor="let criteria of candidate.get('criteriaArray').controls;let j  = index;">

            <div [formGroupName]="j">

              <td *ngIf="EditRowId === candidate.get('id').value"> <input [class.is-invalid]="criteria.errors?.notValid" type="number" formControlName="marks" (click)="changeButtonColor(i)"> </td>
              <td [class.is-invalid]="criteria.errors?.notValid" *ngIf="EditRowId !== candidate.get('id').value" (click)="Edit(candidate.get('id').value)">-----</td>

              <small *ngIf="criteria.errors?.notValid" class="text-danger">Invalid marks</small>
            </div>

          </div>

          <button *ngIf="candidate.get('dataSaveCheck').value === true" type="button" value="candidate.get('id').value" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2" (click)="saveCandidateForm(candidate , i )" [disabled]='!userForm.form.valid'>save</button>
          <button *ngIf="candidate.get('dataSaveCheck').value === false" type="button" value="candidate.get('id').value" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2" (click)="saveCandidateForm(candidate , i )" [disabled]='!userForm.form.valid'>save</button>

        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a demo on https://stackblitz.com. There are few changes that has to be done so it would save time if we have a demo code

Comment: Thanks for taking out time Shashank. I tried making a demo on stackblitz but it is showing some error. I can send you the link to the git repo if you want.

Comment: Sure. that would work too. Stackblitz would have helped you understand better. :)

Comment: https://github.com/sjain24/AlcherJudgingProtal.git